# Angularjs $resource save is not working

Tags: angularjs

i am saving data with $resource but its not working, i am new in angularjs any help will be appreciated.

controller.js

```
$scope.create = function () {
    $scope.risk.createdDate = new Date();
    RiskService.save($scope.risk, function () {
        $('#successModal').modal('show');
        $scope.clear();
    });
};
```

SERVICE.JS

```
RiskService.save = function () {
    return $resource('/app/rest/risk/:id', {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
        'get': {
            method: 'POST'
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: does your request successfully reachs to your rest api with needed data , can you specify your exact problem beacause "not working" means a lot of means.

Comment: How  come the get function has a POST method? Change the method to be GET instead of POST.

Comment: my request is not reaching to rest api

Comment: I don't see a `'save'` method on the service? since you didn't define an actual `'save'` method, try using `$save()`, perhaps.  without seeing the full service.js file, it's hard to understand what you are trying to do by packaging a `$resource` inside a javascript function named save, but you are certainly not executing a save api call here.

Comment: essentially, this `.save` function you created does not really match a traditional signature for a `$resource`.

Comment: @AndrewCounts what is right way to write code for save function to make tradition signature for $resource

Comment: I corrected the get method format for $resource and its working now thanks everyone.